# AngularJS unit tests: Initialize scope of a directive's controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have the following code for a directive using a separated controller with the "controller as" syntax:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('directives.featuredTable', [])

.controller('FeaturedTableCtrl',
['$scope',
function ($scope){
  var controller = this;

  controller.activePage = 1;
  controller.changePaginationCallback =
    controller.changePaginationCallback || function(){};
  controller.density = 10;
  controller.itemsArray = controller.itemsArray || [];
  controller.metadataArray = controller.metadataArray || [];
  controller.numberOfItems = controller.numberOfItems || 0;
  controller.numberOfPages = 1;
  controller.options = controller.options || {
    'pagination': false
  };

  controller.changePaginationDensity = function(){
    controller.activePage = 1;
    controller.numberOfPages =
      computeNumberOfPages(controller.numberOfItems, controller.density);

    controller.changePaginationCallback({
      'page': controller.activePage,
      'perPage': controller.density
    });
  };

  controller.getProperty = function(object, propertyName) {
    var parts = propertyName.split('.');

    for (var i = 0 ; i < parts.length; i++){
      object = object[parts[i]];
    }

    return object;
  };

  controller.setActivePage = function(newActivePage){
    if(newActivePage !== controller.activePage &&
      newActivePage >= 1 && newActivePage <= controller.numberOfPages){

      controller.activePage = newActivePage;
      controller.changePaginationCallback({
        'page': controller.activePage,
        'perPage': controller.density
      });
    }
  };

  initialize();

  $scope.$watch(function () {
    return controller.numberOfItems;
  }, function () {
    controller.numberOfPages =
      computeNumberOfPages(controller.numberOfItems, controller.density);
  });

  function computeNumberOfPages(numberOfItems, density){
    var ceilPage = Math.ceil(numberOfItems / density);
    return ceilPage !== 0 ? ceilPage : 1;
  }

  function initialize(){
    if(controller.options.pagination){
      console.log('paginate');
      controller.changePaginationCallback({
        'page': controller.activePage,
        'perPage': controller.density
      });
    }
  }
}]
)

.directive('featuredTable', [function() {
return {
  'restrict': 'E',
  'scope': {
    'metadataArray': '=',
    'itemsArray': '=',
    'options': '=',
    'numberOfItems': '=',
    'changePaginationCallback': '&'
  },
  'controller': 'FeaturedTableCtrl',
  'bindToController': true,
  'controllerAs': 'featuredTable',
  'templateUrl': 'directives/featuredTable/featuredTable.tpl.html'
};
}]);
```

You can see at the beginning of the controller that I'm initializing its properties with the attributes passed by the directive or providing default values:

```js
controller.activePage = 1;
controller.changePaginationCallback =
    controller.changePaginationCallback || function(){};
controller.density = 10;
controller.itemsArray = controller.itemsArray || [];
controller.metadataArray = controller.metadataArray || [];
controller.numberOfItems = controller.numberOfItems || 0;
controller.numberOfPages = 1;
controller.options = controller.options || {
  'pagination': false
};
```

At the end I'm executing the `initialize();` function that will execute the callback according to the options:

```js
function initialize(){
  if(controller.options.pagination){
    controller.changePaginationCallback({
      'page': controller.activePage,
      'perPage': controller.density
    });
  }
}
```

I'm now trying to unit test this controller (with karma and jasmine) and I need to "simulate" the parameters passed by the directive, I tried the following:

```js
'use strict';

describe('Controller: featured table', function () {

  beforeEach(module('directives.featuredTable'));

  var scope;
  var featuredTable;
  var createCtrlFn;
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    createCtrlFn = function(){
      featuredTable = $controller('FeaturedTableCtrl', {
        '$scope': scope
      });
      scope.$digest();
    };
  }));

  it('should initialize controller', function () {
    createCtrlFn();

    expect(featuredTable.activePage).toEqual(1);
    expect(featuredTable.changePaginationCallback)
      .toEqual(jasmine.any(Function));
    expect(featuredTable.density).toEqual(10);
    expect(featuredTable.itemsArray).toEqual([]);
    expect(featuredTable.metadataArray).toEqual([]);
    expect(featuredTable.numberOfPages).toEqual(1);
    expect(featuredTable.numberOfItems).toEqual(0);
    expect(featuredTable.options).toEqual({
      'pagination': false
    });
  });

  it('should initialize controller with pagination', function () {
    scope.changePaginationCallback = function(){};
    spyOn(scope, 'changePaginationCallback').and.callThrough();

    scope.options = {
      'pagination': true
    };

    createCtrlFn();

    expect(featuredTable.activePage).toEqual(1);
    expect(featuredTable.changePaginationCallback)
      .toEqual(jasmine.any(Function));
    expect(featuredTable.density).toEqual(10);
    expect(featuredTable.itemsArray).toEqual([]);
    expect(featuredTable.metadataArray).toEqual([]);
    expect(featuredTable.numberOfPages).toEqual(1);
    expect(featuredTable.numberOfItems).toEqual(0);
    expect(featuredTable.options).toEqual({
      'pagination': true
    });

    expect(featuredTable.changePaginationCallback).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      'page': 1,
      'perPage': 10
   });
  });
});
```

And got the following error, meaning that scope is not well initialized:
Expected Object({ pagination: false }) to equal Object({ pagination: true })
at test/spec/app/rightPanel/readView/historyTab/historyTab.controller.spec.js:56

Comment: Why would setting properties of the scope change anything on the controller? Does the controller read `$scope.options` and make use of it? You should probably provide the code to the controller itself.

Comment: Parameters are passed by the directive and binded to the scope of the controller with `'bindToController': true`. Controller is using one of these binding properties during its initialization (ie options).  Code of the controller has been provided in the first code sample (see FeaturedTableCtrl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simulating the bindings would be non-trivial - after all, it's hard to really know *what* compiling and linking a directive does with the data passed to it...unless you just do it yourself!

The angular.js documentation offers a guide on how to compile and link a directive for unit testing - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing#testing-directives. After doing that, you'd just need to get the controller from the resulting element(see the documentation for the `controller()` method here - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) and perform your tests. `ControllerAs` would be irrelevant here - you would be testing the controller directly, instead of manipulating the scope.

Here's an example module:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope) {
  var ctrl = this;

  ctrl.concatFoo = function () {
    return ctrl.foo + ' world'
  }
})
app.directive('foo', function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      foo: '@'
    },
    controller: 'FooCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'blah',
    bindToController: true,
  }
})
```

And test setup:

```
describe('Testing a Hello World controller', function() {
  ctrl = null;

  //you need to indicate your module in a test
  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var template = '<div foo="hello"></div>'
    var element = $compile(template)($scope)

    ctrl = element.controller('foo')

  }));

  it('should produce hello world', function() {
    expect(ctrl.concatFoo()).toEqual('hello world')
  });
});
```

(Live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/xoGv9q2vkmilHKAKCwFJ?p=preview)

Comment: I thought about this solution but wanted to avoid to create or use the directive. I guess I will do it if there is no other way.